# Can Optical audio cables / TOS link cables suffer from EMI?

Tags: optical-cable

Can Optical audio cables / TOS link cables suffer from EMI (elector magnetic interference ?)

Comment: Are you experiencing an EMI problem?

Comment: @Ramhound im not but i was reading some manufactures specs and they where saying their cable or jacks had something that mitigated EMI, but i wondered how relevant it was seeing as the cable is fibre

Comment: Visible light is just a certain range of frequencies of electro-magnetic wave, so I suppose if you nick or scrape away the fiber optic strand’s cladding down to the core, it could let some light in, and would technically be EMI. But most of the time EMI refers to RFI, and no, fiber optic links are not susceptible to RFI.

Comment: @sam Monster Cable will happily sell idiot “audiophiles” TOSLINK cables with gold-plated connectors, as if it matters. The cable market, especially in the high-end audio space, is full of charlatans ready to separate idiots from their money.

Comment: The connnectors of optical cables themselves can be susceptible to EMI and RF interference but the cables themselves can’t be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can Optical audio cables / TOS link cables suffer from EMI (elector magnetic interference ?)

They are indeed immune to RF Interference and Electro-Magnetic Interference.

> Fibre optic cables are non-metalli and transmit signals using pulses of light in glass threads! As a result, they are immune to Electro-Magnetic Interference and Radio Frequency Interference.

[Source](https://www.tinygreenpc.com/blog/optical-fibre-immune-to-electromagnetic-interference)

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not. A toslink cable is made out of Optical Fiber(some kind of glass) and transmit data on different light frequencies. Meaning no electricity is transmited, so it won't create a magnetic field to inductancy.

On the other hand, cooper wire if not blinded they catch EMI and distord the signal that is being transmited.